# How to import private API in iOS 10, Xcode 8?

Tags: ios, xcode, private, iphone-privateapi

[image]

Please check the image. Thats what I get when I try import private frameworks.

Comment: what is SBApplicationController?? Is it a class from any framework?

Comment: Storyboard private framework

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are trying to build your application for **simulator** while your library/framework is compiled for the ARM (device) only). The simplest solution is to use device as the target and debug directly on iPhone/ iPad.

Either you can build this framework/library with simulator as target.

The third option - create universal version of framework, which includes binaries both for simulator (X86_64) and for the device (ARM).

If you have no access to source code your only way - debug on the device.

Comment: No I'm trying to build on my iPhone 6s which should be fine??